# Partial match of strings

Tags: string, perl, sed, match

I would like to find a way to do a partial match of strings.

I have two 50-bit binary inputs. If any input is matched with data at least 5-bit in database (array), I would print the input.

Let's say my input is like this. `X` is a "don't care" bit; it would be changed to `.`,

```
11XX1100100010110111110110101001000010110101111111
```

And the data in database are

```
11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111111
11001011011101001000001001010110111101001010000000
00110011011101001000001001010110111101001010000111
```

The first line of data fully matches the input so I will print this.

The second line of data is not fully matched with the input, but the first 5-bit is matched, so I will print this also.

The third line of data is not fully matched with the input, but the 2nd and 3rd bits are matched because of don't care condition and the last 3-bit are matched. Therefore, 5-bit (2nd + 3rd + the last 3-bit) is matched, so I will print this.

I have a Perl script only for fully matched cases, but I don't know how to modify this for the partially matched cases.

#### input.txt

```
11XX1100100010110111110110101001000010110101111111
1000011000111101001011110111001100100101111000010X
```

#### search.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# Read input
open my $input_fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die $! ;
chomp ( my @input = <$input_fh> );

# input
#   11XX11001000101101111101101010010000101101011111X1
#   1000011000111101001011110111001100100101111000010X

# Replace 'X' with '.' which is the regex "don't care" character.                 
s/X/./g for @input;

# Compile a regex made of these two patterns. 
my $search = join ( "|", @input ); 
$search = qr/$search/;      

# Iterate database ( pasted in 'data' block for illustrative purposes )
while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $id, $target, @rest ) = split;
    # print if the target line matches
    print if $target =~ /$search/;
}

# Currently, only fully matched ones are printed 

__DATA__
11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
11001011011101001000001001010110111101001010011111
00110011011101001000001001010110111101001010000111
```

Comment: your requirement has counting in nature. you cannot simply rely onregex to do that, and that means you will need more sophisticated procedure for that?

Comment: I see, then I think character-based search is the only way like zdim's reply.

Comment: Your code doesn't even try to follow the rules that you describe. *Stack Overflow* isn't here to do your job when you don't want to try any more. Regular expressions cannot do this, and you should design and implement an algorithm that does what you need. If you make a genuine attempt and are still struggling then post your code here for help to see what you've missed. As it stands, you're just asking for code to be written for free, and that's unforgiveable.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I did know the rules. If my question and code are not following the rule, I would remove my questions. Sorry about this.

Comment: I tried to remove this post since my cod did not follow the rules. Icannot remove this post

Answer (score 1):

You need to check character by character, so why not break strings up and count

```
sub is_match {
    my ($target, $search, threshold) = @_;
    return if length($target) != length($search);
    $treshold //= 5;

    my @tgt = split //, $target;
    my @sr  = split //, $search;

    for my $i (0..$#tgt) {
        ++$m if $tgt[$i] eq $sr[$i] or $sr[$i] eq 'X';
    }

    return $m >= $treshold ? $m : 0;
}
```

I return the full count, as that may come in handy. But if you only ever care for 1/0, it may makes sense to return early if the strings can be large or are compared many times

```
    ...
    for my $i (0..$#tgt) {
        ++$m if $tgt[$i] eq $sr[$i] or $sr[$i] eq 'X';
        return 1 if $m == $treshold;
    }
    return 0;
```

Note that returning right out of a loop is in general not good practice since multiple (hidden) returns can make the program flow hard to follow. They can also easily be overlooked later.

I've added only a basic check that strings are of equal length. The `undef` returned in that case can be used simply as 'false' if that case is acceptable. If not you can throw a `die` instead.

Comment: An empty pattern like `//` normally tries to match the pattern that successfully matched most recently. But `split` is exempt from this, so that `split //` will correctly divide a string into a list of characters. I think it's always best to use `/` as the delimiter for the split pattern, to emphasize that the parameter is a regex pattern and at least to distinguish between `split ' '` and `split / /` which are very different.

Comment: @Borodin  Eh ... I just can't decide there.  I had `//` at first but then I like `''` to "emphasize" that it uses a literal string. That's probably silly (and moot, it runs regex anyway I think) though.  (Also, I do twitch a little bit at `//` in regex, but that is clear inside `split`.)  Reconsidering...

Answer (score 0):

The following is a fast solution. It performs best when most strings match.

```
sub is_match { ( ( $_[0] ^ $_[1] ) =~ tr/\x00\x68\x69// ) >= 5 }

while (<DATA>) {
   my ( undef, $target ) = split;
   for my $query (@inputs) {
      if (is_match($query, $target)) {
         print;
         last;             
      }
   }
}
```

How it works:

```
    Hex of characters
    =================

    30 30 31 31 58 58  "0011XX"
    30 31 30 31 30 31  "010101"
XOR -----------------
    00 01 01 00 68 69
    ^^       ^^ ^^ ^^  4 matches
```

This solution even works if one of the strings is shorter than the other (since the XOR will result in `30`, `31` or `58` for the extra characters).

Comment: Tested. Fixed problems.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a fast solution. It performs best when there are many queries and/or when most strings don't match.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );
use Regexp::Assemble qw( );

sub make_matcher {
   my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new( flags => 's' );
   for (@_) {
      my $query = tr/X/./r;
      my @query = split //, $query;     #/
      my $extra = @query - 5;
      if ($extra <= 0) {
         $ra->add("^$query") if $extra == 0;
         next;
      }

      NestedLoops(
         [
            [ 0..$#query ],
            ( sub { [ $_+1..$#query ] } ) x ( $extra - 1 ),
         ],
         sub {
            local @query[@_] = (".") x @_;
            $ra->add( "^" . ( join("", @query) =~ s/\.+\z//r ) );
         },
      );
   }

   return $ra->re();
}

my $re = make_matcher(@inputs);
while (<DATA>) {
   my ( undef, $target ) = split;
   print if $target =~ $re;
}
```

It works by creating a large regular expression similar to the following:

```
# For @inputs = qw( 000000 111111 );
my $re = qr/
      ^.00000
   |  ^0.0000
   |  ^00.000
   |  ^000.00
   |  ^0000.0
   |  ^00000
   |  ^.11111
   |  ^1.1111
   |  ^11.111
   |  ^111.11
   |  ^1111.1
   |  ^11111
/xs;
```

The actual pattern:

```
my $re = qr/(?s:^(?:0(?:0(?:0(?:0.?|.0)|.00)|.000)0|1(?:1(?:1(?:1.?|.1)|.11)|.111)1|.(?:00000|11111)))/;
```

This solution even works if one of the strings is shorter than the other.

Note that `make_matcher` could be optimized. I didn't deem it important because it's only called once.

Comment: Tested. Fixed problems.